# Which tag can be used to handle pop-ups on web application like accept/cancel?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am trying to handle pop-ups like accept or cancel. Which tag can be used in pace automation framework to handle pop-ups?

Answer (score 0):

`<alert>` can be used to in case of any pop-up on the web application which requires action by the user like accept/cancel or input from user to proceed, authenticate using username/password to proceed etc.